# Combining .htaccess IP block with AuthType Basic on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to combine basic auth in the apache conf file, with a (long) series of IPs to block in the .htaccess file.

The IP blocking works, but if I switch on the basic auth in the site's conf file, authentication does not work.

My site's conf is as follows:

```
<Directory "/var/www/sites/site.com/">
    Require all denied
    AuthName "Dev Site"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/users
    deny from all
    allow from 1.0.0.0/8 2.0.0.0/8 3.0.0.0/8
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

.htaccess file (IPs to block):

```
<RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not ip 10.1.1.1
Require not ip 11.1.1.1
# ...
</RequireAll>
```

It's as if the .htaccess directives are overriding the basic auth in the conf file.  If I remove the .htaccess file, then the basic auth works as expected.  The .htaccess block list is dynamic, so it needs to remain.

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Thanks